# ReactJS Navigate on a specific route (Router v4)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm kinda new to ReactJS I would like to achieve the following thing with my code -

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Route path="/:page" exact component={PageWrapper} />
    <Route path="/" exact>
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Route>
  </div>
);
```

So I would like to achieve that if user enters /home, /about, /anythingElse as the link it does not navigate, but if user loads a page without passing page parameter, for example - localhost:3000/ or localhost:3000, then it automatically navigates user to localhost:3000/home .

Currently it also navigates to home if user enters a page. I thought exact meant that exact route has to match for it to load.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t nest routes in V4.

You can use the **Switch** component from the router to ensure only one route is matched.

This way all routes that don’t match the **/:page** route will redirect:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/:page" exact component={PageWrapper} />
      <Redirect to="/home" />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

*Remember to import the **Switch** component.*

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!